# VS Code terminal changes places

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, terminal

I accidentally changed the location of my terminal vs code as shown in the picture.[vs code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qhih0.png)

I want to move to the original place at the bottom of the screen. Please help me how to move it in Visual Studio Code

Comment: just drag it to the bottom or any other location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View: Appearance > Panel Position > bottom.

**Follow this image.** **↗️**   [Screenshot](https://ibb.co/dMJkLNt)

Comment: Thank you in advance for answering. I've done what you showed me. However, my terminal still doesn't move. But once again, I accidentally dragged my terminal and it went back to normal. I feel so stupid lol. Thanks again for the help